# Why can't Azure find my TFS project?

Tags: azure, tfs

I'm trying to [setup TFS publishing from within the Azure Management Portal](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-tfs/).

After authorization, one is suppose to select a project. But all I get is:

> Your TFS account has no projects

[image]

But my TFS account certainly has many projects, I can see them when logging in there.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, [just found this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/b6977739-3ee3-48d8-9040-a05a46920ec6/azure-deploy-cant-find-my-repositories).

> Nothing you did wrong.  Deploying from TFS's git repository to Windows
>   Azure is not yet supported.   It is on our radar tentatively mid of
>   this year.

The reason seems to be that my project(s) are Git repositories. (Not TFS repositories)

Comment: If this is the case, you could create a Build that uses the Azure continuous deployment template.  This will then publish this to Azure for you.  All you would need to do is queue a new build, alternatively set up `CI` and do continuous delivery.

Comment: Yeah, hopefully the Azure team adds support soon. Until then if you want to use a build to do the deployment, it's easy enough to do. I've got a blog post describing the steps: http://www.richard-banks.org/2013/08/how-to-deploy-azure-website-from-git_21.html

Comment: @RichardBanks Nice workaround, worked great for me, could you post this as an answer too?

Answer (score 1):

(turning a comment into an answer)

Until Azure supports web site deployments directly from TFService hosted Git repositories you can use an automated build to do the deployment.

Details on how are at http://www.richard-banks.org/2013/08/how-to-deploy-azure-website-from-git_21.html